# why is xhr-polling faster than websockets?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, websocket, benchmarking

I have made several tests with **Node.js** and **Websockets**.

I thought a websocket connection was much faster than **XHR** even if I used **xhr-polling**, but the result is the opposite.

I use **benchmark.js** to check.

If I set the transports option for **Socket.io** to **xhr-polling** Firefox and Chrome do about 300 operations/sec more than with websockets.

But I don't understand why. Can you shed some light into this mistery?